# Button next by inputbox

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input box (JQuery Autopopulate). I would like to add a button next by input field. Below code is showing the very small or minute button. Could someone help me? Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
       <div class ="form-inline">
            <label for="text" >Agent Name or ID</label>     
            <div class="input-group">                  
                <input name="selectAgent" type="text" class="form-control" id="selectAgent" placeholder="type &quot;Agent name or id &quot;" title="type &quot;Agent name or id &quot;">

                <button type ="button" name="addAgent" id="addAgent" class="btn btn-primary"  value ="Add Agent"></button>

            </div>
        </div>

     </div> <!-- col-lg-4 col close -->
    </div> <!-- row close -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button needs to have some text content in it in order to get its proper size. If you don't want to enter text in the button, you can try entering the HTML code for a space.

With text:

```
<button type="button" name="addAgent" id="addAgent" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Agent">Add Agent</button>
```

With space:

```
<button type="button" name="addAgent" id="addAgent" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Agent">&nbsp;</button>
```

Comment: I have value property as "Add Agent"

Comment: The button element needs to explicitly have the text between the tags.

    <button>BUTTON TEXT GOES HERE</button>

Comment: Below lines worked Than kyou very much.<button type ="button" name="addAgent" id="addAgent" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Agent</button>